# How to remove class which are created dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#my").click(function() {
    $(this.title).remove();
});
```

I have work with jQuery dynamically add and remove html content,but how to remove which create dynamically added.

Comment: please clarify "but how to remove which create dynamically added.", Do you need to remove a class from $("#my")?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just try it

```
$("#my").live('click',function()
{
 $(this.title).remove();
}
)
```

Comment: `live` method is deprecated.

Comment: `.live` has been removed in jQuery 1.9!

Answer (score 3):

use on event delegation for dynamically added element

try this

```
 $(document).on("click","#my",function(){
    $(this).removeClass(this.title);
     //or
     $(this.title).remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i suppose

```
$('#my').click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass(this.title);
   $(this).addClass(this.title);  
   $(this).toggleClass(this.title);
})
```

You are looking for one of these?